# Jest - A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs

I have a test file called `integration.test.js`

```
import app from "../app";
import request from "supertest";

describe("testing /users", () => {
  const app = request(app);
  // 5 test cases here. Both use app for api testing
})

describe("testing /images", () => {
  const app = request(app);
  // 6 test cases here. Both use app for api testing
})

describe("testing /blogs", () => {
  const app = request(app);
  // 7 test cases here. Both use app for api testing
})
```

When I run `jest` to run the test cases, it returns a warning

```
A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try runn
ing with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks. Active timers can also cause this, ensure that .unref() was called on them.
```

It also takes around 5 seconds to complete the testing, which seems to be slow

How can I fix the warning and the time of running the test cases?

app.js

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Hello");
});

app.post("/users", (req, res) => {...});
app.post("/images", (req, res) => {...});
app.post("/blogs", (req, res) => {...});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`);
});

export default app;
```

Comment: I am also similar issue but this command hides the warning: "test": "jest --watchAll --detectOpenHandles --verbose". This is under "scripts" in package.json.

Comment: @maverick I don't want to hide the warning. I want to fix it. Is there a way?

Comment: It doesn't actually hide the warning.  You are getting the error because one of the jest workers is not exiting gracefully.  When you run with --detectOpenHandles the tests are no longer run in parallel, they are run linearly.

Answer (score 11):

We struggled with this for a couple of days and finally came up with a fix which works both locally and in our CI (github actions). We were experiencing this issue with using create-react-app plus Firebase-firestore

The trick was that we needed both of the params below to both suppress the message and force the exit.

```
"test": "react-scripts test --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
```

Whether this is covering up a more significant issue remains to be seen

Comment: This won't run test suits in parallel because `--detectOpenHandles` applies `--runInBand` under the hood; `--detectOpenHandles` is aimed for debugging the tests not for use in the final CI environment.

Comment: Weirdly `detectOpenHandles ` finds 0 open handles, yet adding it stops the message about open handles being found.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it's related to asynchronous behaviour, maybe try to use async for test case.

Example:

```
const supertest = require('supertest')
const app = require('../app')
const api = supertest(app)

describe("testing /users", () => {
    test('get all users', async () => {
        await api
            .get('/api/users')
            .expect(200)
            .expect('Content-Type', /application\/json/)
    })
})
```

Comment: I still get the same message when running my tests even with async/await.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to close the HTTP server on test teardown.

Instead of exporting the express.js `app`, you need to export the `http.Server` created from `app.listen`.

```js
export const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Pass `server` instead of `app` into supertest, then on the tests `afterAll` hook, call `server.close()`:

```js
import { server } from "../app";
import request from "supertest";

describe("testing /users", () => {
  const app = request(server);

  afterAll(() => {
    server.close();
  })

  // 5 test cases here. Both use app for api testing
})
```